# Using window.onkeyup in two different JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that uses multiple JavaScript files. I have two event handlers like this in two files:

```
window.onkeyup = function (e) { SomeFunction1(e) }
window.onkeyup = function (e) { SomeFunction2(e) }
```

`SomeFunction1` is in a file that's used in every part of the site but `SomeFunction2` is in a file that's only used in one part of the site.

The problem is that when I include the JavaScript file that contains the handler for `SomeFunction2`, it replaces the handler for `SomeFunction1`, which means the event doesn't trigger any more.

Instead of replacing the `window.onkeyup` handler, I want to add another handler in the javascript file that contains `SomeFunction2` so that both functions are called. How can I do that? jQuery available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `on` event function for this:

```
$(window).on('onkeyup', SomeFunction1);
$(window).on('onkeyup', SomeFunction2);
```

Or using vanilla JS

```
window.addEventListener('onkeyup', SomeFunction1);
window.addEventListener('onkeyup', SomeFunction2);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using the DOM attribute to attach the handler, and there can only be one.

You're better off using the `addEventHandler` API:

```
document.querySelector('foo').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Your code goes here
})
```

OR

```
document.querySelector('foo').addEventListener('click', someFunction);

function someFunction(){
    // Your code goes here
}
```

You can add as many as you want.

Comment: thumbs up for Highlander reference

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery available, you could easily add as many listener as you want

```
$(window).on("keyup", function(){alert(1);});
$(window).on("keyup", function(){alert(2);});
```

Try it on https://jsfiddle.net/45zf9vkd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Add this in a common file:

```
 window.onkeyup = function(e){
     try{
         SomeFunction1(e);
     }catch(e){}
     try{
         SomeFunction2(e);
     }catch(e){}
 }
```

And include your files where `SomeFunction1(e)` and `SomeFunction2(e)` where you need them?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to have multiple handlers for a DOM element e.g.:

```
document.querySelector('#elementID').addEventListener('keyup', function(){...
```

If you already have jQuery set up (it is *not* worth adding jQuery to your site just for this), you can use

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(){...
```

This will only add additional handlers and won't overwrite any existing ones